# Vue.js and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to use jQuery with Vue.js? I have a function this function that I want to use in my Vue component. The function basically slides the items in and out, but when I implemented using the `<script>` tags I got a list with all the items instead of the jQuery code working.

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 5000);
```

How do I use that function in my code?

```
<template>
<div class="timer">
   <div class="title-block">
       <p class="title">MG de Jong</p>
       <p class="description">Sprint 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <div class="block">
         <p class="digit">{{ days | two_digits }}</p>
         <p class="text">Days</p>
     </div>
     <div class="block">
         <p class="digit">{{ hours | two_digits }}</p>
         <p class="text">Hours</p>
     </div>
     <div class="block">
         <p class="digit">{{ minutes | two_digits }}</p>
         <p class="text">Minutes</p>
     </div>
   </div>   
 </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
props: {
   date: {
       type: Number
   },
},
data() {
   return {
       now: Math.trunc((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
   }
},
mounted() {
   window.setInterval(() => {
       this.now = Math.trunc((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
   },1000);


},
computed: {
   seconds() {
       return (this.modifiedDate - this.now) % 60;
   },
   minutes() {
       return Math.trunc((this.modifiedDate - this.now) / 60) % 60;
   },
   hours() {
       return Math.trunc((this.modifiedDate - this.now) / 60 / 60) % 24;
   },
   days() {
       return Math.trunc((this.modifiedDate - this.now) / 60 / 60 / 24);
   },
   modifiedDate: function(){
      return Math.trunc(Date.parse(this.date) / 1000)
   }
},
}
</script>
```

Comment: put the jquery code in the mounted function

Comment: @thankd when I do that I see both the projects and I get the error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You can use It, but try to avoid that unless you really need it.Conceptually those two are different.The thing that you done with jQuery could be implemnted with pure VueJS easily.

Comment: Btw you have to install jQuery via npm, and import it like this `import $ from 'jquery'` and then it should work with mounted hook - or use `jQuery` instead of `$` I think that should work too.

Comment: @BelminBedak how do you get it to work with Vue? Is that possible to replace the function for a Vue function?

Comment: Could you isolate the working jQuery code and put it as demo on jsfiddle, so I can see exactly what this code do ?

Comment: @BelminBedak I followed your advice, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that, but in most of cases, you don't need to.

If you are learning Vue, then try to think in Vue and just put jQuery away. In jQuery, you do things in imperative way; but now you should think in **declarative** way.
Do not manipulate the DOM by yourself directly. All the DOM manipulations should be handled by Vue, you just tell Vue what you want.

Vue provides [Transition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html), your requirement can be done by this without jQuery at all. At first you may think it's not straightforward and want to solve it by jQuery, but once you get the point you will fall in love with it.

Answer (score 1):

As some of he comments mention, you could use a mounted function. For more details you can see this article: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Here is a basic example using cleave.js:

```
<template>
    <input />
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable no-new */
import Cleave from 'cleave.js'

export default {
  mounted () {
    new Cleave(this.$el, {
      date: true,
      datePattern: ['d', 'm', 'Y']
    })

    this.$el.oninput = (e) => {
      console.log('oninput the field', e.target.value)
      this.$emit('oninput', e.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <smart-cleave @oninput="logIt"></smart-cleave>
    <div>{{date}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

/* eslint-disable no-new */
import Cleave from 'cleave.js'
import SmartCleave from './components/SmartCleave'

new Cleave('#plain-input', {
  date: true,
  datePattern: ['d', 'm', 'Y']
})

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    SmartCleave
  },
  data () {
    return {
      date: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logIt (val) {
      console.log('cahnged', val)
      this.date = val
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* text-align: center; */
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```