# AJAX and Vue.js 2 not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I'm trying to use AJAX with Vue.js 2:

```
let remoteUrl = '...................';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: []
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getFilms();
    },
    methods: {
        getFilms: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: remoteUrl
            }).done(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                self.items = res;
            }).fail(function (err) {
                alert("ERRORE: " + err);
            });
        }
    }
```

});

this is the html:

```
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="item in items">
                        <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.data}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.size}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.ext}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

i see the output in console.
But the table remains empty.
I do not see any errors in the AJAX call.
I tried both with created and with mounted.
why?

Comment: Wait, if you see console output, that means the AJAX called succeeded. So this issue you're having is completely unrelated to AJAX. Where is `self` defined?

Comment: You did not declare `self` which you used with `self.items = res`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `let self = {}` below your `remoteUrl` declaration, unless you already declared `self` somewhere else.

This should fix the problem (if `nome`, `data`, `size` and `ext` were properties of your `res` that is).

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why there is a need to use jquery along with Vue. 
If you are using Vue, then just write in Vue.
If you are using ng2/1, then just write in ng2/1.x

This is a big reality and I hate to break it to all Jquery guys:-
As ng5 and by mid-2018 i think ng9 is going to come, no ones going to code in jquery; it will be either jquery alone -OR- angular alone -OR- Vue.js alone.

Meanwhile, all you jquery folks can continue making a hotchpotch of jquery+ng or jquery+Vue, but that is definitely NOT recommended.

I would advise to moveon from jquery, just to stay relevant.
Follow this discussion:
[Vue.js and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728104/vue-js-and-jquery)

Jquery: take it behind the barn and shoot it.
The faster you quit a bad idea, the sooner you can start another idea that shows more promise.

Comment: I don't disagree with the sentiment you're expressing, but this really isn't an answer to the question. At the very least it should point out the Vue equivalent for `$.ajax` https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Answer (score -1):

ok, i substitued jquery with vue-resource.
Now everything works, thank you !!

```
let remoteUrl = '..............';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: []
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getFilms();
    },
    methods: {
        getFilms: function () {
            this.$http.get(remoteUrl).then(response => {
                this.items = response.body;
            }, response => {
                alert(response);
            });
        }
    }
});
```